# Use command once only

Tags: packages, datetime2

Let me straight to the idea:

I want to create a customed document format for diary and journal writting purpose.

The **idea**s is pretty simple, one of them is: I will create a `note` command that will export my text and export automatically the current time in margin note, using `\DTMcurrenttime` command in `datetime2` package.

**Problem**: The problem is I only want to get the current time's value when the command `note` was called and put it in the margin note, not actual 'right now time'. In other words, the time will always be the current time instead of the real taking note's time

**Note**: I haven't had any solution for this cause I not really a pro at coding and just have learned some basic syntax in LaTex to create document =<.

Here is my code look like right now:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showseconds=false]{datetime2} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{fontawesome} % for icons
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
marginparwidth = 90pt,
textwidth = 365pt,
hoffset = 50pt,
marginparsep = 25pt,
}

\newcommand{\notedate}[1]{\marginnote{\raggedright{\faEdit$~~$\texttt{#1}}}
$~$
}

\newcommand{\note}[1]{
\marginnote{\faClockO$~$\texttt{\DTMcurrenttime}}
#1

$~$

}

\begin{document}

\reversemarginpar

\notedate{2021-9-20}

\note{This is a new note created at 8:00am}
    
\note{This is a new note created at 9:00am}

\note{This is a new note created at 10:00am}

\end{document}
```

**Question**: Is there any way to force `\DTMcurrenttime` complie once only for the fist time it was complied along with `note` command and then shut it down, stop it from recompling? Or is there any alternative way to solve this problem ? (yes, i can write the time manually =) , but i want something more 'auto' than 'manual')

Hope you can understand the basic of my idea, my English is pretty bad after all.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Why not just write the time by yourself instead of relying on a command? Indeed, only you knows the "real taking note's time", the time written in the margin with a command being at least the first time this command ran through the compiler.

Comment: A possible approach would be to store the current time and the note contents in a file or database from within LaTeX, and only insert a new entry if you somehow determine that the entry is not yet in the database (unique text? note counter? custom command \startfromhere? all would be a bit fragile). However, that would be rather difficult to implement. If it's ok to use LaTeX just for the output and not for the note taking process itself then you could write the notes in an external program or script and use the datatool package or LuaLaTeX to read the external input.

Comment: However, by far the easiest would be to just write the date manually as suggested by @KersouMan :)

Comment: I know do it mannually will be fine and don't really take to much time to bother =>, I'm just abit curious if it's possible to do something like that in LaTex ~.~. Thanks for the advices !